# Помогите составить паттерн для парсинга

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Здравствуйте, помогите задать паттерн для парсинга.
Имеется следующая строчка:

```
Nov  18 09:35:13,   Probe Request,  c0:ee:fb:35:b6:a0,  Intertelecom_FREE
```

Нужно достать из нее только мак и имя вайфая для строчки

```
pattern = r'ПАТТЕРН'
```

Comment: split по запятой, два последних поля с удалением лидирующих пробелов... PROFIT

Comment: можете на примере строчки показать? Просто я совсем зеленый в этом плане

Comment: Ну так учитесь! Метод вам указан, могу ссылку на страницу дать, где про split написано.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('pineap.log') as log, open("result.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in log:
        _, _, mac, name = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]
       output.write('{} {}'.format(mac, name))
```

Comment: `txt = open('pineap.log').read()
sourse = open("result.txt", "w")

line = txt
_, _, mac, name = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]

sourse.write('{} {}'.format(mac, name))
sourse.close()`

здесь как я понимаю, он мне одну линию читает за целый файл, нужно по циклу for как то прогнать или что

Comment: `mac, name = [x.strip() for x in task.split()][-2:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()
import re
str="Nov  18 09:35:13,   Probe Request,  c0:ee:fb:35:b6:a0,  Intertelecom_FREE"
lst=re.split('[ ,]+',str)
print(lst)#<---['Nov', '18', '09:35:13', 'Probe', 'Request', 'c0:ee:fb:35:b6:a0', 'Intertelecom_FREE']
```